# Outputting array contents as nested list in PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have the array `array ( [0] => array(1,2,3,4,5) [1] => array(6,7,8,9,10))` and I would like to display it like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>
     <a href=""/>FIRST ELEMENT OF THE array ==> 1</a>
     <a href=""/>2ND ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 2</a>
     <a href=""/>3THIRD ELEMENT==> 3</a>
     <a href=""/>FORTH ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 4</a>
     <a href=""/>FIFTH ELEMENT==> 5</a>
 </li>
 <li>
     <a href=""/>6th ELEMENT==> 6</a>
     <a href=""/>7th ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 7</a>
     <a href=""/>8th ELEMENT==> 8</a>
     <a href=""/>9th ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 9</a>
     <a href=""/>10th ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 9</a>
 </li>


</ul>
```

How can I achieve this in PHP? I am thinking of creating a sub array with `array_slice`.

Comment: can you paste php code of array?

Comment: It is incorrect `<a href=""/>`. It should be `<a href="">`

Comment: Your requirements just completely changed...  You shouldn't waste our time coming up with a solution to a problem if you aren't going to give us all of the facts.  Take the time to explain things correctly the first time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
echo "<ul>";
$i=0;
$theCount = count($tab);
while($i<$theCount){
    echo "<li>";
    echo "  <a href=""/>FIRST ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> {$tab[$i]}</a>";
    $i++;
    echo "  <a href=""/>FIRST ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> {$tab[$i]}</a>";
    echo "</li>";
    $i++;
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: Remark that @nikc placed below does apply: this is valid only for even amount of items. Easy -if ugly- fix would be to go to the count()-1, and then do a check if you need to print 1 more.

Comment: This recounts the array on every iteration.  You should isolate the count.

Comment: As an academic speed-up, yes, but I hardly think the question would ask for such optimalizations. nevertheless, I'll fix the 'bug' :)

Comment: Point taken, point taken, but one could argue it is for clarity of the flow for the understanding by the .... owkee, nevermind ;)

Comment: +1 code is now MoarBetter.  Though, you may have a problem with an uneven number of elements in the source array.

Comment: Gys this solution seems to be good, the only proble i forget to say that may array : $ta is an array of array like: $tab ( [0] => array (123) [1] => array (456) ...)

Comment: Do you want to print the "123" as links in the first <li>, and then the 456 as links in the second <li> ? I can update my answer easily for that....

Answer (score 6):

**Updated to take into account your *actual* array structure**

Your solution is a simple nested foreach.

```
$tab = array(array(1,2,3,4,5), array(6,7,8,9,10));
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($tab as $chunks) {
    echo '<li>';
    foreach($chunks as $chunk) {
        echo '<a href="">' . $chunk . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: Removed array chunk after OP changed the requirements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this (demo [here](http://codepad.org/OgmJdwH0)):

```
<?php
$tab = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

//how many <a> elements per <li>
$aElements = 2;    

$totalElems = count($tab);    

//open the list
echo "<ul><li>";

for($i=0;$i<$totalElems;$i++){

    if($i != 0 && ($i%$aElements) == 0){ //check if I'm in the nTh element.
        echo "</li><li>"; //if so, close curr <li> and open another <li> element
    }

    //print <a> elem inside the <li>
    echo "<a href =''>".$tab[$i]."</a>";
}

//close the list
echo "</li></ul>";

?>
```

Tip explanation: $i%n (mod) equals 0 when $i is the nTh element (remainder of division is 0)

EDITED: made a general solution

Comment: I think you should flip this conditional over, and put the block containing the close/open `li` elements first.  It would look easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
for($i = 0 ; $i < count($tab) ; $i += 2) {
    echo "<a href>" . $tab[$i] . "</a>";
    echo "<a href>" . $tab[$i+1] . "</a>";
}
?>
```

Like that.

Comment: This will work as long as there's always an even amount of items in the array. An odd number will cause an index overflow.

Comment: This recounts the array on every iteration.  Would be better to cache that value.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$sections = array_chunk(array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 2);

echo '<ul>';

foreach($sections as $value)
{
 echo '<li>';
 echo '<a href=""/>'.$value[0].' ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==>  '.$value[0].'</a>';
 echo '<a href=""/>'.$value[1].' ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==>  '.$value[1].'</a>';
 echo '</li>';
}

echo '</ul>';
```

Comment: `array_chunk` is definitely the way to go, but an uneven number of elements in the source array will throw an error.

Comment: @Stephen, you are right but a little check if($value[0]), if($value[1]) can sort this problem, but again i agree this isn't the best way of doing it, i myself hav several ways of doing it thinking about it now, but at the time i answered this is what came to my mind...