# Displaying an array content in PHP/HTML

Tags: php, arrays

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Outputting array contents as nested list in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647715/outputting-array-contents-as-nested-list-in-php)

```
I have the array `array ( [0] => array(1,2,3,4,5) [1] => array(6,7,8,9,10))` and I would like to display it like this:

<ul>
  <li>
     <a href=""/>FIRST ELEMENT OF THE array ==> 1</a>
     <a href=""/>2ND ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 2</a>
     <a href=""/>3THIRD ELEMENT==> 3</a>
     <a href=""/>FORTH ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 4</a>
     <a href=""/>FIFTH ELEMENT==> 5</a>
 </li>
 <li>
     <a href=""/>6th ELEMENT==> 6</a>
     <a href=""/>7th ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 7</a>
     <a href=""/>8th ELEMENT==> 8</a>
     <a href=""/>9th ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 9</a>
     <a href=""/>10th ELEMENT OF THE TAB ==> 9</a>
 </li>


</ul>
```

How can I achieve this in PHP? I am thinking of creating a sub array with `array_slice`.

Comment: Seems to be 100% the same as your previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647715/outputting-array-contents-as-nested-list-in-php

Comment: To complete my previous comment: If the answers so far did not help you, you should comment on the answers about what problems you have and/or clarify your original question. Reposting the question does not improve it.

Comment: i very much agree to this, the previous post gave you enough examples to work you way to achieve what you've just asked here...

Comment: owkay gys, i know , i edited it . But it seems it was not seen, that 's why i re-post , am sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

$myArray = array ("0" => array(1,2,3,4,5), "1" => array(6,7,8,9,10));

//open the list
echo "<ul>";

foreach($myArray as $li){
    echo "<li>";
        foreach($li as $a){
            echo "<a href = ''>".$a."</a>";
        }
    echo "</li>";
}    
//close the list
echo "</ul>";

?>
```

Comment: this seems clear , i am tryin it now

Comment: this is the demo: http://codepad.org/shgGNRLR ;)

Comment: there is a problem , my count (array) dsiplay 18 , but in the result i have 144 <li><a></a></li> !!!!

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<ul>";
foreach($yourArray as $subArray){
   echo "<li>";
   foreach($subArray as $value){
      echo "<a href=\"\">".$value."</a>";
   }
   echo "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: am going to try it and i 'ill be back

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using nested foreach or for statements:

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

ie:

```
foreach(element in array){
//output <li>
foreach(element in array item array){
//output a tag
}
//output</li>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$my_array = array(array(1,2,3,4,5), array(6,7,8,9,10));

echo "<ul>\n";
foreach($my_array as $sub_array) {
  echo "\t<li>\n";
  foreach($sub_array as $value) {
    echo "\t\t<a href=\"\">".$value."</a>\n";
  }
  echo "\t</li>\n";
}
echo "</ul>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$arr = array (
 0 => array(1,2,3,4,5),
 1 => array(6,7,8,9,10),
);

echo '<ul>';
foreach($arr as $value)
{
  if(is_array($value) && count($value > 0))
  {
    echo '<li>';
    for($i =0; $i<count($value); $i++)
    {
      echo '<a href="">'.$value[$i].'</a>';
    }
    echo '</li>';
  }
}
echo '</ul>';
```